# This input (type=radio) should not have an aria-checked attribute, as it has a native semantic checked state

Tags: angular-material, accessibility

I am using Angular 9 and material library and I have this code which is throwing the above error. What am I doing wrong?

```
<mat-checkbox aria-label="check me" id="check_me">Check me!</mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: try to clear cache with `npm clear cache -force` and then `npm install`.

Answer (score 3):

[First rule of ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#rule1) is: don't use ARIA if you can use native HTML to achieve the same result.

In this case, `<input type="radio">` doesn't need (and should *not* use) `aria-checked` because HTML already offers a `checked` attribute for that type of element. If you're setting `aria-checked`, it's the wrong thing.

It *could* be that the developers of `mat-checkbox` do not know this, and is rendering the element state using `aria-checked` rather than `checked`. If so, that's their bug.

Incidentally, I don't think you need `aria-label` here either, because the element has a text node which is presumably visible on screen. (You could also use a `label` element.) You should remove it.

`aria-label` should be reserved for cases where there is no onscreen text label (such as a button labeled with an icon or an image), or in the much more rare cases where there is an intention to provide a label to assistive technology which differs from the onscreen text label for some reason.

Note that `checked` is a boolean attribute, which means it does not require a value (and will be treated as "true" even if you give it the value "false"). For a false value, omit the attribute entirely.

Answer (score 0):

**Accessibility**
MatCheckbox uses an internal `<input type="checkbox">` to provide an accessible experience. This internal checkbox receives focus and is automatically labelled by the text content of the  element. Avoid adding other interactive controls into the content of , as this degrades the experience for users of assistive technology.

Always provide an accessible label via aria-label or aria-labelledby for checkboxes without descriptive text content. For dynamic labels, MatCheckbox provides input properties for binding aria-label and aria-labelledby. This means that you should not use the attr. prefix when binding these properties, as demonstrated below.

```
<mat-checkbox [aria-label]="isSubscribedToEmailsMessage">
</mat-checkbox>
```

https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview